# Keyframe Animation only working in Internet Explorer

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, safari, keyframe

I am trying to add this scroll animation script to my website: http://codepen.io/zutrinken/pen/yhqEA

```css
#scrolldown {
  bottom: 40px;
  height: 100px;
  margin-left: -50px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100px;
  z-index: 100;
}
#scrolldown p {
  font: 700 0.7em/1em 'Avenir',sans-serif;
  animation-duration: 2s;
  animation-fill-mode: both;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  animation-name: scroll;
  color: #000;
}
#scrolldown > p {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-indent: 3px;
}
.mouse {
  border: 2px solid #000;
  border-radius: 13px;
  display: block;
  height: 46px;
  left: 50%;
  margin: 10px 0 0 -13px;
  position: absolute;
  width: 26px;
}
.mouse span {
  display: block;
  font-size: 1.5em;
  margin: 6px auto;
}
@keyframes scroll {
  0% {
    opacity: 1;
    transform: translateY(0px);
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0;
    transform: translateY(10px);
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="scrolldown">
  <p>scroll</p>
  <div class="mouse">
    <span><p>&darr;</p></span>
  </div>
</div>
```

The animation works in Chrome while in Code Pen but i can not get it to work outside of Code Pen. **How Can I get this script to work with other browsers?**

http://rapidevac.biz/tapreport/ This is my website that i added the script to. Like i said, it works with IE 9 but not with other browsers.

Thanks guys for reviewing my question!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this after your @keyframes scroll to se the animation in all browsers

```
@-moz-keyframes scroll {
  0% {
    opacity: 1;
    transform: translateY(0px);
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0;
    transform: translateY(10px);
  }
}

@-o-keyframes scroll {
  0% {
    opacity: 1;
    transform: translateY(0px);
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0;
    transform: translateY(100px);
  }
}
@-webkit-keyframes scroll {
  0% {
    opacity: 1;
    transform: translateY(0px);
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0;
    transform: translateY(100px);
  }
}
@keyframes scroll {
  0% {
    opacity: 1;
    transform: translateY(0px);
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0;
    transform: translateY(10px);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your transitions are not cross-browser friendly.

Change your #scrolldown p css to this:

```
#scrolldown p {
    font: 700 0.7em/1em 'Avenir',sans-serif;
    animation-duration: 2s;
    animation-fill-mode: both;
    animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    animation-name: scroll;
    -webkit-animation-duration: 2s;
    -webkit-animation-fill-mode: both;
    -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    -webkit-animation-name: scroll;
    -moz-animation-duration: 2s;
    -moz-animation-fill-mode: both;
    -moz-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    -moz-animation-name: scroll;
    -o-animation-name: scroll;
    -o-animation-duration: 2s;
    -o-animation-fill-mode: both;
    -o-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
 }
```

Comment: Thank you for the fast response Andrew. I have added your suggested piece of code to my css but it still does not work. I added it to `#scrolldown p {`  and `#scrolldown > p {` Am I missing something?